# Add a shallow resource as member of another resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm using rails routing, i'd like to have something like

```
resources :user
  member do
    resources :comments, shallow: true
  end
end

# To get the following routes
get /users/:id/comments (index)
post /users/:id/comments (create)
get /comments/:id (show)
put /comments/:id (update)
delete /comments/:id (destroy)
```

However shallowing does not work, I'm having the following routes (not to mention that the `:id` for the user and the comment are conflicting)

```
get /users/:id/comments
post /users/:id/comments
get /users/:id/comments/:id
put /users/:id/comments/:id
delete /users/:id/comments/:id
```

I know that usually the recommended way of doing is

```
resources :user
  resources :comments, shallow: true
end

# To get the following routes
get /users/:user_id/comments
post /users/:user_id/comments
get /comments/:id
put /comments/:id
delete /comments/:id
```

but I want to have the `:id` in the `params` instead of `:user_id` on the shallowed route create/index. [This is usually done by using `member`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

> You can leave out the :on option, this will create the same member
>   route except that the resource id value will be available in
>   params[:photo_id] instead of params[:id].

**Does anyone knows why the shallowing does not work properly when done inside the `member` directive ?**

Answer (score 0):

The `member` directive is used to add member routes to an existing resource, not to nest resources. I personally think that having `:id` refer to the parent resource in the index and create actions is unclear/confusing but if you're really bothered by using `user_id` in the controller, you can setup your routes in the following manner

```
resources :user do
  resources :comments, shallow: true, except: [:index, :create, :new, :edit]
end

get '/users/:id/comments', to: 'comments#index'
post '/users/:id/comments', to: 'comments#create'
```

That will give you the following routes

```
GET /users/:id/comments
POST /users/:id/comments
GET /comments/:id
PUT /comments/:id
DELETE /comments/:id
```